# %%writefile magic command in regular Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am copying Python code from [Jupyter Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/toshikazuwatanabe/connect4-make-submission-with-stable-baselines3/comments) to .py file to run it from a terminal.
I could not find a way how this line should be implemented:

```
%%writefile -a submission.py
```

What is the same code in regular Python as %%writefile magic command does?

Comment: I just read what this does.  It writes the contents of a Jupyter Cell to the specified file.  What would you expect this to do in isolation, like you've shown us?  What is the definition of "the cell" in regular Python, the contents of which should be written to `submission.py`?  The direct answer to your question is to say, "rewrite all of Jupyter" if you want to reproduce what `%%writefile` does. - If you really want something more modest than that, you need to explain what the behavior is that you want from this line of code given the context it is running in, and what that context is.

Comment: Can't you just copy-paste your code from cell to file?.
You can use `cat source_code.py >> submission.py` in your terminal to do so

Comment: `%%writefile` is defined in an `ipython` terminal session, but not a regular `python` session (interactive or not).

Comment: @Steve, your comments made it clear - it is just writing Python code into a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replaced this:

```
%%writefile -a submission.py

    model = Net()
    model = model.float()
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    model = model.to('cpu')
    model = model.eval()
    obs = tensor(obs['board']).reshape(1, 1, config.rows, config.columns).float()
    obs = obs / 2
    action = model(obs)
    return int(action)
```

by this:

```
submission_ending = '''    model = Net()
    model = model.float()
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    model = model.to('cpu')
    model = model.eval()
    obs = tensor(obs['board']).reshape(1, 1, config.rows, config.columns).float()
    obs = obs / 2
    action = model(obs)
    return int(action)'''

with open('submission.py', mode='a') as file:
    file.write(submission_ending)
```